# Default conditions and columns with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm using Symfony2 with Doctrine. I have tons of entities (tables) and here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

**PROBLEM**

Every entity needs to have 2 fields (columns), for example `from_date` and `to_date` by default.
Suppose I have the following entity defined in the `product.orm.yml` file:

```
Some\Random\Namespace\Product:
    type: entity
    table: product
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            length: 255
        description:
            type: text
        price:
            type: float
```

After I would run `doctrine:schema:update` the created table should already have `from_date` and `to_date` columns.
Now, lets say I'm trying to fetch all the products from the database. I would do it like so:

```
$products = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SomeRandomBundle:Product')->findAll();
```

This would normally fetch ALL the products from the database. What I would like to do, is to fetch only products where `from_date` <= `some_date` <= `to_date`. There would be a function `getSomeDate()` that Doctrine would have to call in order, to get the value of `some_date`.
Not that it should also work with custom queries written in DQL or if I do something like this

```
$products = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SomeRandomBundle:Product')->findByPrice(20);
```

However, it should not affect cases, where I try to fetch the entity by it's PK using the find method or custom DQL query.

**ADDITIONAL DETAILS**

There would also be some entities, that would not follow the above rules.

I know I could create `from_date` and `to_date` in every entity + perform the check, but since there will be thousands of queries in the application it would only make code less readable.

**GOAL**

The goal of the above is to allow user, to see the state of the application as it was, anywhere in the past. If you know a different approach that can achieve the same goal it would also be great.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To add custom fields to all your entities u can

   - use [mappedSupperclass](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) with additional fields
   - use [loadClassMetadata](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/events.html#load-classmetadata-event) event listener/subscriber
2. To make an additional checks when fetching the data you could also set [custom repository](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories) class where findAll/findBy uses custom DQL with additional checks
3. To add additional checks when executing DQL queries you can specify [DQL custom walkers](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-custom-walkers.html)

Comment: That looks nice. The only thing I don't know yet, is how to extend repository class for all entities? By the way, sorry for late response. My laptop got broken so I had to get a new one.